# Get current route in order to "grey out" a corresponding link in a nav bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I am currently working with Laravel 5, I've setup my different routes and I have a "sidebar.blade.php" with a classic nav bar in it. I want to be able to "grey out" the page the user is currently on, which means if he is @ "website.com/store", I want the "Store" link on the navbar to be greyed out.

I know how to do this using JavaScript ( `addClass`, for instance ), but I'd like to know how to get the current "route" in order to assign the class to the good link. I've heard about `window.location.hash.split('\')[1]`, but the issue here is I got links like "website.com/store/1" and "website.com/event#1".

Thank you in advance for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

You should add the logic to include the class on server side rather than client. Of course you can also do it with Javascript, you just need to know how to parse it right. For the menu, I'd do in in PHP.